# postgresql learning tips/resourses for database a novice

Tags: database, postgresql

I am a database novice and I really need some advice to help me get started with postgresql.

I have some basic knowledge on relational database but have never used any database management system before; I have some programming experience with R but don't know how to use a command line interface.

After some research, I set my mind on postgresql, but I find it difficult to get started, and here are some reasons:

1. Most of the books I find are for database adminstrators who have some background and experience, the content provides too much details and is somewhat overwhelming for a beginner with little practical experience.
2. Most tutorials are command line based, but again, I don't know how to use command line(although I feel like I will be learning it in near future).

I don't intend to become a very skillful database administrator for the purpose of developing applications; the reason I want to learn a database management system is that I want to design a data model for my research team and implement it. My team is conducting a cohort study with a thousand of observations and several thousands of variables. Although it might not be a necessity that we deploy a relational database, but doing it the hard way is error prone and cumbersome.

So, are there any books, tutorials or other resources that suit my background and needs? Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Your question is off topic. See [what topics you can ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Did you read the Postgres tutorial from the manual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [the fine manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/index.html), it is the best place to learn about SQL and PostgreSQL.

Comment: The question is essentially "what is the best way to learn about PostgreSQL?" So I think my answer is appropriate. If anything, the question should be closed as being too broad.